# Django 2.0.7 I keep getting this error'int' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django-views, python-3.6

Every time i click the upload button i run into this error i have tried several different solutions but none of them to seem to work

This is the line that causes the error, in my views.py:

```
        form = uploadForm(request.FILES,instance=userId)
```

where userId is defined as

```
userId = request.user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working example how to define instance

```
r_id = YourModelName(restaurant_id = request.user.restr_id, status = 1)
form = YourFormName(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = r_id)
```

if you show your Model, i can give ready code for your case